# HED Tomcat disc, 24h, 21mm internal width

Tags: tire, rims

What's the smallest size tire that will fit these rims: HED Tomcat disc, 24h, 21mm internal width

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange Bicycles.

That is a good question - and one that is answered very well already in this post: [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)
.  Have a look at that and see if it helps.