# how to know what kind of tires work for my fork?

Tags: road-bike, fork, upgrades, gravel

I want to know how select the tire depends on the bike or fork because actually I have the following problem.

Currently, I have a specialized diverge whit this fork. Specialized FACT carbon, flat-mount disc, 12x100mm thru-axle. I want to change my tires for a continental speedride 700x42c. how I know if this kind of tire work on my bike.

Comment: The fork has very little to do with your tire choice.  Your wheels are the main issue -- what is the rim diameter, what is the rim width.  After that, the limiting factor is clearance, but that more likely to be an issue with frame and brakes than with the fork.

Comment: my rim is 622x21 axis sport the tires I have are 700x35c  I saw this post 

https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle?newreg=4ab243d156524e9caf8d16af66f3ad7b

and the wheel accepts that tires or I am incorrect? I guess my width is 21.mm and accept the 42 tire width.... but I don't know if space is enough, the new question is how to know if I have space for that tires?

Comment: From what I remember with Specialized bikes, most road variations will only accept 32c max where most of the cyclo-cross / gravel will take up to a 42c

Comment: @DanielRHicks I do not agree. For a gravel bike it is the fork that will be limiting the tyre clearance in the front. 42c is well within the limits of the rims typically sold with gravel bikes but the fork might only allow it with 650B.

Comment: @Conan, which actual fork it is? What bike is it on? Specialized Diverge or some other kind of bike? A gravel bike or a road bike?

Comment: What year is your Diverge? Is it marketed as a gravel/road/touring bike? You can always try your luck and write to the manufacturers (both) and ask their opinion.

Comment: My diverge is Diverge Elite E5 2020, is marketed like gravel.  I guees is this: Specialized FACT carbon, flat-mount disc, 12x100mm thru-axle
  
actually the specs are the follow: https://www.specialized.com/mx/en/diverge-elite-e5/p/171309?color=264792-171309

Thanks@Vladimir F  @EarlGrey I will try to write.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What year is your Diverge? 
Unfortunately Specialized states that for the Diverge 2021

*Tyre clearance increased to 47mm (700c) / 2.1in (650b)*

So it is quite likely you will have issues (I guess they increased it of more than 5 mm, to make such a claim, and therefore you would be at the limit of the accepted size, which is always calling for possible issues due to minor difference between the measured clearance and the effective size&shape of the tyre). 
I would suggest trying some 700x38, the Hutchinson Overide 38 have a similar pattern to the one you wanted (see review here: [site I am not affiliated with but possibly informative](https://www.cxmagazine.com/hutchinson-overide-tubeless-gravel-tire-review-35-38/2) ).

From the pattern of the Speedride I guess you are looking for a gravel tyre,  today you have plenty of choice for alternative to the Speedride 700x42.

Comment: Thanks, I will see the page... I'm new in this world and I don't know exactly how to know if the shape are correct. I select the speed ride because I saw a review on the same ground I road.  And my problem is don't know a lot of brand in tires.

Comment: Yes, I know it is not easy to know about tires. I personally remember some tyre on my touring bike, the 1.5" (38mm) was good but giving an harsh ride on old asphalt and forest road, the 1.6" (~40mm) tyre was good and quick, the 1.8" (~45mm) felt very slow.
Back to your bike: I found a comment here shorturl.at/zF259
stating that for the Diverge E5 Elite, FACT fork, 58cm [...] Specialized states this bike will fit up to 38 mm tires, that is in fact not 100% accurate. The large chain ring limit will interfere with any rear tire that exceeds 35 mm. The front will fit 37/38 mm no problem

Comment: I can't access the link. thanks for your help! now is more clear

Comment: @Conan ok, the correct URL is https://www.specialized.com/us/en/mens-diverge-e5-elite/p/129178 , the text I quote is from one of the review at the bottom of the page. The comment is from 2 years ago, so it should be for a Diverge 2017 or 2018 ... it's tricky to give exact advice, but regarding your opening question the answer seems "it does not work". Try to email Specialized, they may have a guess.