# Can i fit 26 x 2.3 tyre to 559 x 19c rims?

Tags: rims, 26-inch, tyre-width

If yes, is there a problem?
And what is the max tyre width for that rims?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you read https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle ?

Answer (score 4):

It will be on the squirrely and unstable side, especially if ridden aggressively, but this combination was common when narrow MTB rims were more fashionable and ubiquitous, so it will in all likelihood function without major incident. You can do it but probably shouldn't.