# Turning MTB to hybrid

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, hybrid-bike

I have one mountain bike with its own tyre. I would like to turn that to a hybrid. My MTB tyre size is 26×2.125 57-557 what size should I purchase if I am going with hybrid tyres?

Answer (score 2):

You obviously need a tire of the correct diameter for a "26 inch" wheel - These may be marked 26" or ISO / ETRTO 559.

Generally you'll want a tire narrower than a MTB tire for on-road use. Narrower tires running a higher pressure have less rolling resistance.

How much narrower is up to you depending on the roads or trails you want to ride on, but you are limited by the width of the rim. See [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle).

Comment: Just to point out the obvious: Tire construction, tread and pressure will have a much larger impact on rolling resistance than 5mm more or less of width.

Comment: @Michael the pressure depends on load and on tyre width. What is more, fast rolling wider tyres, that is those with some casing, are nearly always very expensive and flimsy. A cheap 28 (eg Ulra Sport) might roll almost as well as a fast 40 mm tyre (eg Compass).

Answer (score 0):

I have done exactly that using tires marked 26 x 1.5 and run them between 60-80 psi.

Good success measure is I've been up to par with riding mates of similar physical condition than me but they riding proper road bikes.

Answer (score -2):

go for narrow tyres in 26” or get apair of 700c road wheels these will fit straight into a 26” mtb frame.Never seen a 26” frame that didn’t take 700c wheels

Comment: The assumption here is that the wheels are all disk brakes.  If not, this swap is not feasible.