# A road bike with bad tires to gravel bike upgrade

Tags: road-bike, tire, upgrades, gravel

I have a road bike with tyres that aren't that great I want to upgrade for more wider and gripper tyres any recommendations?I desperately need it.The old tyres are Triban Protect 700 x 28 tyres. Tyre weight: 440g Anti-puncture protection Supple carcass for light weight Max pressure: 8 bar /116 psi. 48mm Triban inner tube with Presta valve

Comment: Any tyres you want to put on need to fir into the fork and between the rear stays and into the brake calipers if you have rim brakes and leave enough room for picked-up mud or dirt.

Comment: See [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle) for advice on maximum width tires you can install. Product recommendations are off topic here as they have a limited audience and time span that they are useful.

Answer (score 3):

How much clearance do you have?

The rear tire has to fit between the rear seat stays, chain stays and rim brakes (if you have them). Front tire has to fit through fork and rim brakes (if you have them). A wide front tire can also increase toe overlap (i.e. your toes hitting the wheel in tight turns).

You’ll probably want to go as wide as you can. If you plan to ride in mud you’ll need more clearance.

Take a look at cyclocross or gravel bike tires.

On soft surfaces like mud or snow you’ll need knobby tires. On gravel tread is not that important. For maximum grip you should lower your pressure as much as possible.

Comment: On gravel, width is more important, otherwise the tyre tends to knife-down between the rocks, depending on their size, smoothness, and compaction.