# Replace my 28 x 1-5/8 x 1-3/8 tires with beefier ones for flat gravel trails

Tags: tire, replacement

This is my first post!

My wife has a great old aluminum hybrid bike that works very well on paved roads. We are now doing more backcountry flat gravel trails and I don't want to replace the entire bike.

Can you please tell me what size of tires I can buy to replace the current 28 x 1-5/8 x 1-3/8?

Thank you so much!

Comment: The size you quoted is ambiguous, adding a photo of size markings on the tire will help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Answer (score 3):

Tire sizing is a very funny thing. The size you list could be on one of two different rim sizes, either 622 or 635 (https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html). The tire should have another marking on it after the size you listed, something like 622-32. That tells you the actual rim size. Hopefully it's 622 as that is much more common. You may be able to fit a wider tire, but that depends on the design of the bike frame. You can look to see the spots on the frame where the tire comes closest to rubbing. If there is extra room, you should be able to fit a wider tire.

Comment: Hello Noah, thanks so much for getting back to me so quickly! Indeed, the tires are 37-622. I looked at the clearance. The front is about 1/2 inch, maybe a little more, while the back tire is about 1 inch. I hope this helps!

Comment: You might be able to go up to something like 42-45mm wide tires then. It really will just take some experimentation to see what will fit unless the bike manufacturer happens to publish a maximum tire width (most don't).

Comment: Thank you so much!