# Buying new wheels for Evo Sport E5 cyclocross to fit slimmer tires

Tags: road-bike, wheels, rims

I've read some similar posts on this topic but would like to check that I understood correctly.  A replacement of my stock Tracer 700x33c tires on my Specialized Evo E5 Sport cyclocross is overdue and I'm unsure about my options.

My rims have 16.2mm internal 23mm external according to https://www.rockandroadbikes.com/products/axis-wheel-elite-disc. This means the tire I want to fit, the Continental Grand Prix 5000 TL (28 x 1.00, 25-622) will be ok. (See table in the top answer of [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle))

If I were to buy a second pair of wheels would be a second pair of the stock be a good choice?

**Edit:**
*I edited my question after I realized that I miss read the rim to tire size coversion table in the question referenced in the comments.*

**Edit:**
*Turns out I read the table correct the first time and then changed my question for the worse.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Comment: See the newly edited question

Comment: I just realized I miss read the table the second time not the first. i guess buying the 28mm slicks should not be a problem in that case

Comment: "would be a second pair of the stock be a goos choice" - if you mean buying same rims, I wouldn't. These looks very outdated, 16.2mm/23mm width is too narrow if you compare to current CF rim offerings. If I were in the same position, I'd opt for 28, 30mm or even 32mm outer width rims.

Comment: Ok, so what do I need to look out for? And would you put the new rims with the slicks or the new with the knuby ones?

Comment: @FlyingSwissman sorry, but only you could know whether narrower or wider tires suit your riding conditions and preferences. As a general rule, you can list limiting factors (comfort, conditions, price, weight and so on) and then see what fits the requirements. Or you can try both and see what works better, maybe lend a wheelset from a friend?

Comment: I want both. One rim with narrow 28mm and one wider with a wider tire.

Comment: I'd keep old wheelset for 33mm tires and get a modern, aero rim for narrow tires. Motivation: according to the so called "105% rule" (more like rule of thumb), 28mm wide / 45-50mm rim would be more aero and faster compared to old narrow rims (you'd have to mount obsolete 21mm tires to get more aero with these). This might work for you, assuming you want to go faster with narrower tire, so more aero fits the requirements. For example, my current setup is 26mm tires on 28/45mm open mold CF rims.

Comment: Buy the best rims you can get for the money you are prepared to spend. Stock rims won't be the best. If your thinking about stock rims, consider why the first upgrade many people with a new bike is wheels -on most bikes its an easy improvement .