# Question about 700 x 33c bike tire

Tags: tire

I currently own Schwinn Millsaps Road Bike 14 speeds cyclocross. I ride my bike mostly on pavement. I want to replace the current 700 x 33c bike tires with Diamondback Interval Road 700X32 Tire Folding Bead 700 cm X -700 x 32c bike tires which have much less road resistance.   Is it ok to do so? Or any idea about any faster bike tires?   Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle). Note product recommendations are specifically off topic here, so the last bit is unlikely to be answered.

Comment: 1mm of width difference on a bicycle tire is within the margin of error of measurement.

Comment: By the way, it looks like Diamondback Interval Road is exclusively sold in big box stores and Amazon, not bike stores. This does not mean they are bad, but it is suspicious.

Comment: There are tyres that are known to be good at that price bracket. One example is Conti Ultrasport. Check https://www.bicyclerollingresistance.com/ for more.