# Tire compatibility

Tags: tire, frames, rims

[My bike](https://www.firefoxbikes.com/firefox-target-21-speed/) has a 19.5 inch frameset (49 cm) and rolls on a pair of 26 x 1.75 BTWIN Trekking tires. I want to go for thinner tires and I came across a [set of 27.5 x 1.2 tires](https://www.decathlon.in/p/8386247/bike-inner-tubes-and-tires/resist-9-slick-275x12-flex-bead-protection-mtb-tyre-etrto-30-584) on the Decathlon webpage . I am intrigued to know if these tires would fit on my rim. I'm not planning on changing the tires I have now as they are pretty new (Around 300 km), but I wanted to know to map a future plan.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you looked at    https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle   ?

Comment: Why thinner tires? Are you sure you fully understand the pros and cons?

Comment: ...but they are waterproof! I've never seen a tire marketed as waterproof before.

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate, since it's about tire width and the problem here is diameter.

Answer (score 3):

No. Your current tires are so-called 26 inch and they fit on 559mm rims. The tires you are considering are so-called 27.5 inch and fit on 584 rims.

If you for some reason buy new wheels to match the tires, they do not fit your bike. It is likely that they are too large to fit at all, and if they do, rim brakes are in wrong position for the larger rim.