# Can I fit 27.5 or 29 tires on 700c rims?

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, rims, touring-bikes

Id like to go with wider tires, but there is not tires 2.0 inch that is made for 700c rims.
So is there any alternative to that?

Comment: There are definitely 2.0-in wide tires made for 700c rims. https://www.schwalbetires.com/bike_tires/G-ONE_Speed

Comment: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html

Answer (score 7):

700c is the same rim bead-seat diameter ETRTO-622 and the same as road 28" and the same as MTB 29" (29er).

So yes, you can fit 29" tyres on a 700c rim (of course, subject to the tyre and rim width compatibility [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)).

Your confusion may stem from the fact that while it is common in the MTB world to call this wheel size 29" (the approximate outer diameter of the tyre), in road and hybrid bikes it is commonly denoted as 700c or 622 (the rim size) and the outer diameter of the tyre is often more like 28" just because the road, gravel or hybrid tyres are smaller.

Comment: Made a slight edit to clarify 700c/622/29er have the same rim diameter

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus Well,my intention was literally to say that these different names for the same thing, not that they just happen to have one of the dimensions the same...

Comment: I could add that 27" tires have roughly 27" outer diameter and they fit slightly larger rims than common 28" and 29".

Answer (score 7):

Vladimir is correct that 700c and 29er rims have the same bead-seat diameter. However, it's important to keep in mind that rims have a limited range of tire widths that they can handle, and 2" tires might exceed the maximum width of your rims. The rim manufacturer will probably have a tire-size guide, something like [this](https://www.wtb.com/pages/tire-rim-fit-chart).

Also, even assuming the rims can handle the tires, you'll want to make sure that the tires will fit your frame and fork. Chainstay clearance and fork-crown clearance in particular can be a problem. I've even discovered that the front derailleur can interfere with tires that are too wide.

Comment: Well, the OP wants just 2.0 inch, I think even 17 mm rims ought  to work, that's why I didn't comment about that. https://www.schwalbe.com/files/schwalbe/userupload/Images/FAQ/reifen_felgen_2020/Reifen_Felgenkombinationen_2020_EN.pdf

Comment: I see you also point to a particular table. It seems to be really conservative, it shows the combination I got with my gravel bike (17mm rim) as just "compatible" and I even increased the tyre size later on. But the original would be withing "Schwalbe recommendation" for even a smaller 15 mm rim and the current still for a 16 mm rim.

Comment: I'm trying to cover all possibilities, in case someone else with a similar question reads this in the future. Also, tubeless tires generally have more stringent fitting guidelines, and serious consequences for incorrect fit.