# Put larger tires on my road bike rims

Tags: road-bike, tire

My rim size is 622-20 and my current tire is 622-30

Can I fit a 622-35 or a 622-40 tire on my rim?   My forks are wide.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Comment: According to the question, 622-20 is rim, not tire size.

Comment: My current tire size from the store is 622-30

Comment: I would like to go up to a 622-47 if possible..... I have not measured the inside diameter of the rim but 622-20 is stamped on the rim. With a 622-30 tire.

Answer (score 1):

Is 20mm really the inside width of your rim? Would be unusually wide for a road bike (I think currently around 17mm are most common). If it’s really 20mm inside width you can mount anything from 32 to 63mm wide tires on that rim. According to Schwalbe as narrow as 25mm would also be okay: https://www.schwalbe.com/files/schwalbe/userupload/Images/FAQ/reifen_felgen_2020/Reifen_Felgenkombinationen_2020_EN.pdf

Of course you need enough clearance in the fork, frame and (if you have them) rim brakes. Very wide (and therefore high) tires can also increase toe overlap on the front wheel (i.e. your toes hitting the front wheel in tight turns).