# I'm wanting to know what the thinnest tires i can put on my gravel bike are

Tags: tire, gravel

I'm looking to buy thinner tires for my gravel bike my bike has Weinmann U28 TL rims and right now has 700*40mm tires do I need to buy new rims to put 30mm tires in. On Weinmann's website, they say the  U28 TL doesn't come in a 700c variant so I can't find it there. The bike is a 2020 Khs grit 220 if that helps at all

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle   Try reading that and apply to your situation.   It really depends on your rim's inner width.

Comment: Hmm, this page says it comes in 29", which is equivalent to 700c. It gives an internal width of 23.4mm. At my answer on Criggie's link, you have enough info to see that by the 2015 ISO specs, your rims technically support 37mm tires at minimum. However, that spec is outdated. People mount 28mm tires on some rims with 25mm internal width these days. https://www.weinmanntek.com/product/21/52

Comment: Yes that helps thank you.