# Am i getting the correct tire and inner tube?

Tags: tire

So I have a Raleigh bike and I have to change the back tire  and inner tube but don't know which one too choose I did write the  number listed in the bike tire and a few options showed up when I Google it  I just don't know if it's correct, I listed the photos of the options of the bike tire and inner tube  that showed up on Google as well as
Which should I choose

Here is the numbers that are on the bike tire ( sorry I don't know anything about bikes)

Min .50 - max 8.5 psi ( 3.5 - 5.9 bar -350 - 590 kpa )

32-622(700×32c-28× 1/5/8 × 1 1/4 )

[This link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0030RSFQ6) is for the tire I found. [This is](https://www.target.com/p/bell-700c-28-34-standard-bike-inner-tube-black/-/A-81637979) for the inner tube.

(Editor's note: OP provided links to a Schwinn branded 700c, 38mm tire, and a Bell tube with a Presta valve rated for 35-43mm tires.)

Comment: Looks good, assuming you have a pump which works with the presta (road bike) valve on the tube. I don’t know if the items are a good choice (we don’t really have Bell or Schwinn here in Europe), for that price you can almost get some nice Schwalbe or Continental tubes+tyres (e.g. Schwalbe Marathon).

Comment: Just to clarify, the numbers you pasted into the original post appear to be a 700c, 32mm tire. Those are the numbers written on your current tire. Correct?

Comment: Weiwen Ng yes those are the numbers on my current tire

Comment: Then while you have to dig a bit, there's valuable information in this answer. The problem is that the people there were trying to answer two different questions: does X tire fit my *rim*, and does X tire fit my *bike*. https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: Note that the numbers, defining the acceptable pressure range, entered into the question at this time (Min .50 - max 8.5 psi... ) are not correctly transcribed as they should be 50 - 85 psi.  This is a common range for a bike tire and also corresponds to 3.4 to 5.8 bars, as correctly noted in the question. Hopefully the tire/tube manufacturer hasn't made the error, though it wouldn't be catastrophic since even at 8.5 psi the tire would be mostly flat and not rideable.