# Can I put wider tires on my bike or does that depend on the size of the frame?

Tags: tire, fork, size, trek

My 2005 Trek 4300 currently has 26x1.95 tires on it. I was wondering if I could put wider tires on my bike. I don't want to spend money on the tires if they're not going to fit on my bike. This might seem like a simple question but I am actually wondering if this would work.

Comment: The tires need to fit into the frame and fork. If you have mudguards on your bike, they need to fit under them, too. So, have a look at the amount of space you have, leave a few mm of air gap, and that tells you the width of the tyres you can fit.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This is absolutely a duplicate question - we have one with generic advice about changing tyre size - but can't find it :(

Comment: @AndyP is this the question you're looking for https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: Just cannot be you want putting 29" tires on 26" rim. They will just pass over, how would you imagine this could possibly work? Hence the question is probably about the WIDTH only, and then this is a duplicate.

Comment: Be aware that you've never said how you want to use this bike.  If it is for street-riding, you want something different from aggressive off-road jumps and fast turns.    Consider joining [chat] rather than asking a stream of questions.