# Can I fit thinner tires on this bike?

Tags: tire, electric-bike

I'm looking into buying the Orbea Vibe H10 (or H30). But the tires are a bit too bulky for my taste. Would it be possible to fit this bike with some thinner tires?

[image: Bike]

I like the aesthetics of something like this with the "tann wall".

[image]

Here is the specifications for the bike.

[image]

Comment: The question is really how wide is the inner width of your rims.  Nothing else is relevant when going to a narrower tyre width.   You probably want to read through https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: I'd recommend that you select tires based on functionality in your riding environment - ride, durability, traction, etc. - as the primary criteria and prioritize aesthetics somewhere toward the bottom of the criteria list.

Comment: @Criggie if starting from a bike designed for tires 2.4” - 2.8” wide, dropping the bottom bracket too low can be a concern, especially in technical terrain. I run 2.6” tires on a hardtail designed around 3.0” tires and it’s noticeable.

Comment: @PaulH interesting!  Based on Sheldon's table, tyre widths for a specific rim internal width can range about 40% of the maximum size.  So at best OP's 45mm tyre could go down to about 32mm, and half that difference-drop in the BB/road height.  Hard to see, but could be the difference between pedal strike and not when cornering.

Comment: If tan wall is what you care about, you could also choose to replace the stock tires with something like the tan wall version of the panaracer pasela (protite version or not) in tan wall 700x35, or the tan wall herse tires in similar width, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can.  The rim widths aren't stated but I'd be pretty certain you could go down to 35mm, and probably 32mm.  [Here's](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tyre-sizing.html) a rather cautious compatibility chart.

However I wouldn't do so until you've got the bike in your hands.  The specs are nonsense so you can't be sure what you'll end up with:

- "Frame: 700x40  max tire"
- "Tires: Kenda 1052 700x45"

So either the specs are a lie or the tyres supplied won't fit.