# Widest tire for 559 rim 26"

Tags: tire, rims

Anyone know the widest tire for a 559 rim? I haven't had much luck finding one.

I am currently running 26 x 2.12, I am looking to go little bit wider for smoother rides.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: While it depends on the width of the rim, you can likely go a few mm wider without any issue. Your bike manufacturer was probably not pushing the limits of the rim width in its initial spec. Some further information here: https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for your responses. Is there a specific vendor where I can browse/choose the rims sizes etc., (besides amazon etc.,)