# Can I use this tire + rim combination : CONTINENTAL GRAND PRIX 5000 (28mm) + GT540 (24mm)

Tags: tire, rims

I have the rim **DT Swiss G 540**, which inner width is **24mm**.

I already bought the CONTINENTAL GRAND PRIX 5000 tires **28mm** (saw this advice on reddit).

But now I checked the official [table](https://www.dtswiss.com/pmt/00/00/00/00/00/00/00/10/00/00/00/86/6/MAN_WXD10000000866S_WEB_ZZ_001.pdf) and see that they do not fit together very well... :(

**Rim:**
[image]
**Acceptable tires:**
[image]

The tire width is only 2mm less! What do you think - can I use it or better not?

On my last trip the tire came off the rim - but not sure if the tire size is the reason or I just overinflated it by CO2 cartridge:
[image]

Comment: The fact that it came off speaks for itself. Doesn't it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Comment: Have you got a link to the reddit post?

Comment: Thanks for the link! Good explanation! Now it becomes more clear…

Comment: And the link to Reddit the post: https://www.reddit.com/r/bicycling/comments/mrdnae/upgrades_to_specialized_diverge_sport_carbon/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf

Comment: Thanks - the reddit guy said "I just have the stock tyres on there now. So pathfinder sport 700x**38**"  meaning a drop of 13mm to get 25m wide tyres.  That's an enormous change, and is really pushing the limits.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its clearly not-recommended by the rim manufacturer.

On top of that, the tyre has come off for you proves that its a bad combination.

That it is only 2mm is immaterial - it came off and could have severe consequences.

There is no glue or strap or ziptie or bodge-fix that will allow you to use this tyre and rim combination safely.

Your options are to buy a wider tyre, or replace the rim with something narrower.   A 32 or 34mm tyre would be cheaper than a new rim, presuming the rest of your frame provides clearance for a wider tyre.

If your front rim is the same inner width, the same advice applies.  If your front rim is narrower, then it *might* work with this tyre.

Comment: Thank you for the great answer! Before I wasn't sure, but now it is clear!

Answer (score 0):

I raced crits for 2 seasons now with my farsport gravel rims 24 internal rim width and hookless... with 28mm GP 5000 S TR.  So maybe 5 cat 1/2/3 crit races and about 15 cat 3/4 crit races with this set up (and all my training rides).  during all that I and never had an issue, super solid cornering grip with this setup.

Results may vary. Not liable if you wreck and hurt yourself or anyone else.

Comment: Advertised tire width is not the same as the actual width, which is what the table in the question is referring to.  For example, I run a 25 width tire and they measure out to 28.  Have you actually measured your actual tire width as mounted?