# Can I put a 27.5x2.00 tire on my 27.5x2.195 rim? If yes, will it have a problem with the frame if its to big?

Tags: tire

My tire size is 27.5x2.195 or 125 I'm not sure, but my question is can I put a 2.00 tire in my 2.195 or 2.125 rim? Will it have a problem with the frame being to big for the tire?

Comment: Welcome, I first suggest to read [What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: But be careful, I assume that those `2.75x2.195`is **your current tyre** size, not your rim size. For a rim, you should not care about the current tire too much. You should care about the **internal width of the rim**. Try to get or measure the that dimension. It is almost certain that there will be no problem, those tyre sizes are very similar, but you should look at the rim width.

Comment: Minor edit - is that what you meant to ask?