# Cube 150 downhill tyre size question

Tags: tire

I currently run 27.5 x 2.3 snake skin schwalbe tubeless tyres, it had an inertube in ? Also can I use another width other than 2.3 ? If so how far can I go ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Answer (score 1):

TLDR: You can probably use up to 2.6” tires without thinking about it.

There are two things to take into account.

The width of your rim. If it’s a recent model it might have Newmen Evolution SL A.30 rims with a 30mm inner width. If not grab a ruler and measure the distance between inside the rim walls. You don’t need a super accurate reading. To the nearest mm is fine.

This [chart](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html#width) shows conservative values for max tire width but from experience 30mm will take up to 2.6” tires with no issue.

The other thing to consider is frame clearance. If the tire is too large when inflated, it may not clear the frame. At the extreme end of the possible range you’d need to check with your suspension totally compressed at both ends by letting all the air out of your shocks and squishing the tyre at low pressure to find the limit.

As the bike is a DH frame you can expect it to accept fairly large tyres within limits. 2.8” is heading into “plus” sizing and wouldn’t work well on a 30mm rim and may start messing with geometry.

Comment: Thanks Warren  I don’t really want to be going much more than 2.35 as they are and would 2.25 be ok ?

Comment: Should be fine. It’s a 2.5mm change. This chart here is nicer to look at for MTB tyres https://www.wtb.com/pages/tire-rim-fit-chart