# Am I able to swap out my 20x2.35 bike tires with a 20x2.15 sized tire?

Tags: tire

I am currently trying to replace my current bike tires with studded ones for winter but the closest ones I could find were only 2.15. Would it be a safe idea to use these ones?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Answer (score 1):

There is no universal answer; it depends on the bike. Losing the 0.2" or 5mm of pedal clearance with the ground may not seem like much and on most bikes for most riders it will indeed be completely negligible.

The sticky point is when you've got a bike where, say, pedal strike in use has been able to happen, or you can observe that it's close from leaning the bike on its side a reasonable amount. In those cases, where strike is a possibility within normal habits already, the 5mm could make a meaningful difference in terms of the lean angle where it's encountered, or the height of obstacles.

In this era 20x2.35 is a common cargo ebike size. The best cargo ebikes play a good balancing act with BB height to get the center of mass low, so you can't just go giving way more of it without examining what the effects will be firsthand.

Since you're talking about studded tires, there's also the question of how likely it is you'll be railing turns in those conditions anyway. Probably not very, and if that's true then likely there's even some benefit in getting lower. It's up to you.