# How can I determine the maximum tire width that my Shimano bike frame and fork can accommodate?

Tags: shimano, tire, tyre-width

A wider tire width, ranging from 2.3 to 2.6 inches or more, offers better traction and floatation in loose conditions, helping to prevent the tires from sinking into the terrain.

How can I determine the maximum tire width that my Shimano bike frame and fork can accommodate?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  Just to be clear, you're asking about available space and minimum clearance, correct?

Comment: @DavidW Yes, that is what I am asking about.

Comment: Shimano bike frame? Really? Anyway, the first step will be the actual space that is there in the frame where the tyre comes. And then you have to state what gap is sufficient for you. To avoid mud, but also to provide enough clearance for the mud or for fenders - that is quite individual. If you want specific sdvice for specific frames, you will have to show the details.

Comment: @VladimirFГероямслава Shimano do not make frames, but they have had rebranded ones at events like product announcements, etc.  Apparently Felt have supplied frames for this in the past.

Comment: Sorry, the ƒclause in my previous comment should have been "to avoid rub", that is the most important and necessary, but not sufficient, condition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the maximum tire or minimum tire width I can fit on my bicycle](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle)

Comment: Quite a few bike frames are labelled "Shimano *equipped*", which means that the components fitted are made by Shimano. Normally from a special range of products they only sell to manufacturers of cheap bikes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shimano is a manufacturer of bike components. You need to find the information about tire clearance of the bicycle frame and fork, find the make/model and find the information about it on the website of the frame manufacturer, and if a different company, the website of the front fork manufacturer.

If you are unable to find it, borrow the tires from a friend and test it on your bicycle. Have in mind that there is an ISO standard for tire clearance.

> The ISO 4210-2:4.10. 2 standard for tire clearance states that a
> minimum of 4mm of clearance must remain between the tire and any frame
> element.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on tyre clearance (and rim width).

To determine how much clearance you have it’s easiest to already have a wheel+tyre installed. You can then measure the remaining clearance with a ruler or even better: Use hex keys of various thickness and find out what the widest hex key is you can fit in the gap. Check that it really fits in all the gaps i.e. also between rear wheel and front derailleur, everywhere between rear wheel and seatpost and so on.

For a road bike 2 – 3mm of clearance (on each side) is the bare minimum, for off-road bikes a whole centimeter is a good idea. Even more if you plan to ride in sticky snow or mud.

Answer (score 1):

the fork manufacture set the front tire max limit. frame manufacture set the rear tire max limit. I did not think Shimano makes shocks or forks or bike frames.