# What is the min / max size of tyres that can be used on BTwin MyBike with 26" wheels?

Tags: hybrid-bike, tyre-width

I was given a 2016 [BTwin MyBike](https://www.decathlon.in/p/8304742/hybrid-india/adult-leisure-cycle-my-bike-white?id=8304742&type=p)

It had come with stock **1.95"** tyres, and later were upgraded to **2"** tyres

I wish to change the tyres, i am wondering if i could put **2.10"** or more wider tyres maybe?

I checked the website information, but i couldn't find any info on the rim width

Comment: Check out https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/ and measure your frame at the points where its close.  Remember whgeels and tyres and frames all flex too, so you need some spare.

Answer (score 3):

[image: btwin mybike wheel rim inner width]

The width of the inner rim wall is around **23mm.**

Went through the [link](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle) shared by **@Criggie**

Safe to use tires in the range of: **1.45" - 2.70"**

Comment: Nice work!   yeah a thinner tyre is generally fine, but with a wider tyre you have to start considering everywhere it might rub.   And that the frame will flex a little while riding too.

Comment: Yea, have to keep the frame distance in mind before replacing the tyre. 
The frame was stretched by a few centimeters to accommodate a 7s freewheel, which gives a lil more clearance for the rear tyre.

The frame is steel, not sure how much it would flex when compared to aluminium.
Have to keep some clearance so the wheels don't rub against the frame while cornering / slopes.

I am planning for 2.10" tyres, I think I could get away with 2.30" tyres

Comment: The rim tape looks very shady though. 

Ive come to learn that for single walled rims, fabric rim tapes are ideal. 

I am using tube tyres btw.