Fuji Transonic road bike 2019 rim brake - tire width?
I have a Fuji Transonic road bike from 2019
Current tires are 25mm.  Can I put 28mm tires on it?

Do you mean 25 inches (25") or 25c?

Welcome. I guess you actually mean  25 mm and 28 mm. I also suggest to take the [tour].

I can't find firm specs, but looking online for various images of your bike it really looks like it's too tight to go to a wider tyre.  (The wiggle in the seat stay is like they intentionally made it so it wouldn't take a wider tyre.)

I've clarified the measurement.   Please have a browse of the generic advise on https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/52587/what-is-the-maximum-tire-or-minimum-tire-width-i-can-fit-on-my-bicycle    and see how your bike frame would go with more width and height at the pinch points of chainstay, seat stay, brake calipers, and forks.   Remember you need some tolerance for frame flex and rubbing is wasted watts and a damaged frame.

No, you cannot put 28" tires on a bicycle that has 25" tires.
However, your tires are not 25" tires. They are 28" tires. The 622mm bead seat diameter, often sometimes called 700C, is the 28" tire size although in road bike tires the diameter is closer to 27". It is in mountain bikes called 29".
So only your tire width would change. The 622-25 tires (700C 25mm) would be replaced by 622-28 tires (700C 28mm).
This might or might not work. The worrying part here is the fact that your bike appears to be a road bike and has 25mm tires and rim brakes.
Rim brakes are generally lighterweight and firmer the shorter reach they had. So then began a trend towards shorter reach, which meant tire clearance was poor. If the rim brakes have clearance for only 23mm tires, then often times the frame and the fork also had clearance for only 23mm tires, without fenders (so apparently the cyclist never rides in the rain, based on the theory that it might be a good idea to not equip a bike with fenders).
Your bike may not be the worst bike ever made, since the tires are not 23mm but 25mm so there appears to be little more clearance than the worst bikes had, but 28mm is a big step upwards and only you can determine if it works by measuring.
28mm tire is 1.5mm wider on left and right sides (separately), and about 3mm taller. So measure if the left and right sides at the fork, at the seatstays, and at the chainstays have at least 1.5mm more clearance, ideally far more since the tire needs space to rotate, and running out of clearance with an unloaded bike can cause the tire to rub the frame, fork or brake when loaded.
Also you need to have at least 3mm more clearance at the top of the tire, ideally far more since you don't want the tire to rub the frame, fork or brake.
I would actually say that 5mm additional clearance with new tires is ideal, so if you let's say have only 5mm more clearance at top, it would be 5mm-3mm = 2mm with 28mm tires, somewhat too little.
If you want wider tires, let's say 32mm, I would recommend selecting a road (or more ideally gravel or touring) bike with disc brakes. Fortunately today they tend to be equipped with disc brakes, which allow lots of tire clearance without weight issues.
